# How to use <canvas> generated with *ngFor in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, canvas, ngfor

I am trying to create a list of `div` elements which contains `canvas` elements using `*ngFor` directive in my Angular app. After `(click)` event on a particular `canvas` I would like to update the array (which I iterate over with `*ngFor`) at the relevant index and draw a shape on that `canvas`.

I've tried to set a reference to every `canvas` via `#elementRef` in my `*ngFor` loop and pass the reference to my drawing function (`myDrawingFunction(elementRef)`), but after array updates the function cannot properly locate the clicked canvas to draw on.

Do you have any suggestions what is the best approach to achieve this?

Thank you have much for any help!

Comment: was my answer useful?

Comment: It still doesn't work as intended

Comment: I'll try that on a stackblitz

Comment: I've corrected few stuff and added a stackblitz demo

Comment: I'd like to update the array at arr[index] in the myDrawingFunction(i). When I add a line of code eg. this.arr[index] = 0; in the function, it doesn't work. When all the values in the array are not changed, your code and also mine seems to work fine. But I still would like to make changes in this array.

Comment: can you provide code please

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yjvhhm?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/list/list.component.ts

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look tomorrow

Comment: I've added some corrections to my answer

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly for 1d array. But I am struggling with implementing it in my app where I use 2d array. I am sorry I have not mentioned it before. Could you please take a look at my code and tell me how to write trackByFn function to make it not track changes in 2d array? Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yjvhhm?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/list/list.component.html

Comment: simply add trackFn to the ngFor with the j index

Comment: [stackblitz](https://angular-ivy-dytkpq.stackblitz.io)

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using an index in your html as so then use elementRef and the specific id to retrieve the element and manipulate it **you also need to imperatively make usage of trackBy** your dom may be messed up after the update of your array:

```
<div *ngFor="let a of arrayOfIndexes;index as i; trackBy:trackByFn">
  <canvas attr.id="canvas-{{i}}" (click)="myDrawingFunction(i)"></canvas>
</div>
```

and in your ts

```
...
arrayOfIndexes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
...
constructor (private el:ElementRef){}
...
trackByFn(index){
  return (index);
}
myDrawingFunction(index:number){
  //here you retrieve your element by id eg: '#canvas-2'
  let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#canvas-' + index);
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d') //just an example
  ...
}

...
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1w2lgt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcanvas%2Fcanvas.component.html)

***REFERENCE***

[ngForOf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Comment: I've never seen the `*ngFor` with parenthesis before, is that valid?

Comment: @Phix sorry my mistake only a typo the code hasn't been tested

Comment: Behaviour of the canvas list is the same as in my #elementRef example. Function draws shapes on the canvas, but not always on the clicked one. Sometimes click event on a canvas causes erasing a shape from another one instead of drawing on the proper one.